# Using Ruby, how do I print just the value of a MongoDB query result

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to print just the value of the field in question (`name`). What it does now is print the following.

```
nameHOSTA
nameHOSTB
```

I want it to print

```
HOSTA
HOSTB
```

Query ...

```
puts collection.find({"environment_name" => role, "type" => "TF"}, {:fields => {"_id" => 0, "name" =>
    1}}).to_a
```

Comment: When I run something like you have above, I actually get back a hash:

{"name"=>"hostA"}
{"name"=>"hostB"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should get you want you want:

```
collection.find({"environment_name" => role, "type" => "TF"}, {:fields => {"_id" => 0, "name" =>1}}).each { |item| 
    puts item['name'] 
}
```

Comment: That freaking did it. THANKS!